# What to do when the .img is corrupted?

Tags: linux, firmware-analysis

After getting rejected from a promising interview process with Company A, the interviewer reached out to me and provided me with Reverse Engineering challenges Company A provides publicly to work on.

What I've done: (disclaimer: I'm still a Novice)

- extracted the .img as firmware.img
- file firmware.img
  **output:** Linux kernel ARM64 boot executable Image, little-endian, 4K pages
- strings firmware.img
  **summary:** gibberish until what looks to be stuff for a tcp/udp server
- xxd firmware.img
  **summary:** all bytes are 'ff' from 00036650 - 000aade0

Tools that did not work (incompatible file?):

- binwalk
- objdump
- readelf

Other things that failed:

- mount

This is the part I'm currently at, is I'm unable to mount the firmware.img, but the errors keep saying "corrupted" as I try different ways to mount the file.

What recommendations or different approaches should I consider?

Comment: I'm guessing due to not knowing anything about the binary you were given...but, perhaps it's worth trusting the output of `file`? To start, you can probably plug the output of `file` into a search engine to find documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This img file is identified by `file` as a Linux kernel boot image.

This type of file is (sort of) a self extracting archive, not a filesystem `.img` that is mountable.

There is a standard Linux tool to extract this file:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/extract-vmlinux

Extracted file can then be analyzed using the tools you mentioned to get more meaningful results.